# add path to .bashrc in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I seem to be having a problem setting path so that it permanently stays for a user.  If I add to path by:

```
export PATH=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.139:$PATH
```

and then verfify by `echo $PATH` I can see that path gets temporarily added until the user closes the terminal.  What is the correct way to add path to `.bashrc` and to `echo $PATH`?  Thank you :).

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.139 >> .bashrc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu, .bashrc isn't always run by default. If you see the top of the comment in Ubuntu .bashrc code,

```html
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
```

there is an option to run bash terminal as a login shell or not as describe above. With Ubuntu, gnome-terminal does not normally run as a login shell, so .bashrc should be run directly.

By default, Ubuntu uses only .profile and default .profile has the following statements

```html
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This runs .bashrc if it is available assuming $BASH_VERSION is present in your environment. You can check for this by entering the command echo $BASH_VERSION, and it should display some information on version number and if $BASH_VERSION isn't set by default, .bashrc won't run on startup. Hope this helps :)

Comment: So then `export PATH="$PATH:/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.139"` would add path to .profile and `source .profile` could be used to verify this?  Then whenever I called `picard` the `.profile` already has the path in it permanently? I know this is asked a lot but it is something that is very confusing and I haven't grasp it completely.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: you can just add it into .profile rather than using .bashrc (i know centos runs on .bashrc during interactive shell), whenever you boot up or reboot, it will automatically source .profile by default but if you make any changes to .profile, you'll need to source it or just do . .profile instead of source .profile  both works the same.  make sure there isn't others such as .bash_profile and etc which takes higher priority. You can read more about [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others)